# I want to make this modal window appear after 10seconds when the page has loaded..tnx everyone

Tags: javascript, jquery, dialog, window, modal-dialog

$(document).ready(function() {

```
    var id = "#dialog";

    //Get the screen height and width
    var maskHeight = $(document).height();
    var maskWidth = $(window).width();

    //Set heigth and width to mask to fill up the whole screen
    $('#mask').css({'width':maskWidth,'height':maskHeight});

    //transition effect     
    $('#mask').fadeIn('fast');  
    $('#mask').fadeTo('fast');  

    //Get the window height and width
    var winH = $(window).height();
    var winW = $(window).width();

    //Set the popup window to center
    $(id).css('top',  winH/2-$(id).height()/2);
    $(id).css('left', winW/2-$(id).width()/2);

    //transition effect
    $(id).fadeIn('fast');   

//if close button is clicked
$('.window .close').click(function (e) {
    //Cancel the link behavior
    e.preventDefault();
    $('#mask').fadeOut();
    $('.window').fadeOut();
});     

//if mask is clicked
$('#mask').click(function () {
    $(this).unhide();
    $('.window').unhide();
});
```

});

Comment: In general, you should ask your question in the body and use a descriptive title. The code you posted is not relevant to your apparent question, hence the downvotes.

Answer (score 1):

Hide the modal window when document is loaded,  using the setTimeout() method show, the div

Check this code.

```
 $(document).ready(
    function(){
        $("#dialog").hide();
        setTimeout(function(){
            $("#dialog").show();
        }, 10 * 1000);  
    }
);
```

Comment: where do i insert setTimeout() in the above script? since var id="#dialog"; is the div that is shown when the page is loaded..

Comment: please check the edited answer for the code hints. I havent checked it , but it should work for you.

Answer (score 0):

To execute a function after a delay, you can use `window.setTimeout(fun, milliseconds)`. It's common to use this with anonymous functions. For example, if you want to do something 10 seconds after the page loads:

```
$(function()
{
    setTimeout(function()
    {
        alert("Something");
    }, 10 * 1000);
});
```

Comment: where do i insert setTimeout() in the above script? since var id="#dialog"; is the div that is shown when the page is loaded.

Comment: The short answer is to wrap all the lines from `var id = ...` to `$(id).fadeIn(...` in an anonymous function called via `setTimeout`. That's not the best solution, but if you've never worked with JavaScript before it's probably the easiest thing to do.

Comment: im still newbie  with this js thing.. =(

Answer (score 0):

Regarding the code above just paste

```
//set a delay on load
$('#mask').delay(5000);
```

Right after the below code

```
//Set heigth and width to mask to fill up the whole screen
$('#mask').css({'width':maskWidth,'height':maskHeight});
```

After that paste

```
//set a delay on load
$(id).delay(5000);
```

Right before

```
//transition effect
$(id).fadeIn(2000);
```

I hope this helps.